# Issues with DataView

Tags: dataview

I have a client that is having issues while in DataView.

1. He is unable to drag the cells while in DataView like you can in
   Excel, other users at his location have no problem doing this. He
   can copy and paste the cells though
2. When he enter's a Document Meta Tag he gets a drop down with a bunch
   of String#Agreements in the list. Here is a screenshot:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v4Zv.jpg

I have downgraded him from IE 11 to 10 to 9, their site is added to trusted sites and also in compatibility mode.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: try to run IE in compatibility mode? also try to use different browser? Clear IE cache...

Comment: It's already in Compatibility mode and cache is cleared

Comment: Anyone else have any more ideas to try?